# How to perform Greater than Operator in MongoDb Compass Querying inside inner object collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my Json in Mongo DB Compass. I am just querying greater than rating products from each collection.

Note: if I am doing with pageCount it is working fine because that is not inside a collection.

**`{PageCount:{gte:2}} -- works.`**

Problem with inner arrays collection of collection if anyone matches it displays all.

When we are doing the below query if anyone of the index have greater than 99 it shows all the values.

```
{"ProductField.ProductDetailFields.ProductDetailInfo.ProductScore.Rating": {$exists:true,  $ne: null , $gte: 99}}
```

----- if I perform above query, I am getting this [image] output.

How to iterate like foreach kind of things and check the condition in MongoDB querying

[image]

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5fc73a7b3fb52d00166554b9"
   },
   "ProductField":{
      "PageCount":2,
      "ProductDetailFields":[
         {
            "PageNumber":1,
      
            "ProductDetailInfo":[
               {
                  "RowIndex":0,
                  "ProductScore":{
                     "Name":"Samsung",
                     "Rating":99
                  },
                 
               },
               {
                  "RowIndex":1,
                  "ProductScore":{
                     "Name":"Nokia",
                     "Rating":96
                  },
                  
               },
                {
                  "RowIndex":2,
                  "ProductScore":{
                     "Name":"Apple",
                     "Rating":80
                  },
                  
                   
               }

            ]
         }
      ]
   }  
},
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5fc73a7b3fb52d0016655450"
   },
   "ProductField":{
      "PageCount":2,
      "ProductDetailFields":[
         {
            "PageNumber":1,
            "ProductDetailInfo":[
               {
                  "RowIndex":0,
                  "ProductScore":{
                     "Name":"Sony",
                     "Rating":93
                  }
               },
               {
                  "RowIndex":1,
                  "ProductScore":{
                     "Name":"OnePlus",
                     "Rating":93
                  }
               },
               {
                  "RowIndex":2,
                  "ProductScore":{
                     "Name":"BlackBerry",
                     "Rating":20
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

@Misky How to run this query execute:
[image]

While run this query in Mongo Shell - no sql client throws below error. we are using 3.4.9 https://www.nosqlclient.com/demo/
[image]

Comment: What result do you expect from that document in your post? By the way `{"yourLongThing": {$gte: 99}}` this is enough cause any numer bigger than 99 exists and is not null XD

Comment: search will be on multiple documents as inside a document collection  consider 2 collection - each document ProductDetailInfo Array has a Product Rating and I need to filter based on rating.of the document whichever have greater than 99 rating. if you see the screenshot , i have doing gte:99 but it shows below the values. if it is not in nested collection gte works

Comment: @Minsky if it works as per you can you put the above-posted json and try with gte and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this somewhat close to your idea

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
    "ProductField.ProductDetailFields": {
      $map: {
        "input": "$ProductField.ProductDetailFields",
        as: "pdf",
        in: {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              $map: {
                "input": "$$pdf.ProductDetailInfo",
                as: "e",
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $gte: [
                        "$$e.ProductScore.Rating",
                        99
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$e",
                        {
                          PageNumber: "$$pdf.PageNumber"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    null
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            as: "i",
            cond: {
              $ne: [
                "$$i",
                null
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $addFields: {
    "ProductField.ProductDetailFields": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$ProductField.ProductDetailFields",
        0
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[LIVE VERSION](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IsXFJbvSQoj)

Comment: yes it's working thanks for your time  do you know how to run in MongoDB compass or pipeline script . ith throws a syntax error.

Comment: if it solved, please accept the answer @MohamedSahir. was tough work

Comment: yes . I have already tried in compass with adding stages something wrong what i add in syntax. so then i tried with our hosted mongodb NoSQL client, it have aggreagate dropdown functions, there i removed the db.collection.aggregate({}}); below lines and pasted execute the query . i have  added image there.could you please look into reply means it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Could you please help to connect me in skype  or chat free2fly.sahir@gmail.com. Still i am facing issues with that it is not run in NoSQL client - https://www.nosqlclient.com/, thttps://www.nosqlclient.com/demo/  else can you create one collection in that client and makes workable also fine for me.

Comment: ya no problem, I am new to MongoDB and i can able to write queries in robo3t ,command all tutorials are provided the reference for command prompt or syntax-based query but when try to query inside compass or NoSQL client not works. But ur provided query also little complex .

Comment: I have executed your query in nosql mondodb shell and attached a image for reference it throws below version error :`WARNING: No implicit session: Logical Sessions are only supported on server versions 3.6 and greater.
Implicit session: dummy session
MongoDB server version: 3.4.9
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match`- attached detail error as image . is there any other ways to do it without merge

Comment: 3.4 is ancient, `mongod` is in 4.4 now. $mergeObjects is on 3.6 and after. 1. you could upgrade `mongod` to 3.6 version. There may be other ways but that's really time consuming. @MohamedSahir please, don't extend discussion here, either chat, or email, or make a new post. So to be clear, **the problem is not the client, but the server**

Comment: yes sudden ugrade  is not possibel as of now .anyway thanks i can close this now